# How to add multiple validation parameters in a marshmallow schema

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, validation, marshmallow

I have the following schema in one of my class models:

```
class SocialMediaSchema(Schema):
    facebook_profile_url = fields.String(required=False, validate=validate.Length(0, 71, 'Facebook username is too long.')
```

Aside from validating the length, I also want to be able to make sure that `facebook_profile_url` is never equal to the string `"http://www.facebook.com/"`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can pass a list as the `validate` parameter:

```
class SocialMediaSchema(Schema):
    facebook_profile_url = fields.String(required=False, validate=[
        validate.Length(0, 71, 'Facebook username is too long.'),
        lambda x: x != "http://www.facebook.com/"
    ])
```

From the [documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Field):

> `validate` (callable) – Validator or collection of validators that are called during deserialization.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering what's wrong with this validate parameter:
`lambda x: x == '' or validate.Regexp('https://facebook.com/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z 0-9._]$', 0, 'Facebook username is invalid')`. Basically, it's supposed to accept an empty string or a string that follows the regex pattern.

Comment: Presumably `validate.Regexp()` returns a function, so you'd need to use `... or validate.Regexp('https://...', 0, 'username invalid')(x)`. You should be able to skip the lambda and just use a regex like `^$|https://facebook.com/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z 0-9._]$`, though.

Comment: Or you could just make the URL optional: `^(https://facebook.com/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z 0-9._])?$`

Comment: It is also possible to use `marshmallow.validate.And(*validators: types.Validator, error: str | None = None)`. It is a bit more explicit and you can pass a custom error message. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088043/how-to-add-multiple-validation-parameters-in-a-marshmallow-schema